# In Matlab GUI, how get the figure handle of an external plot?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, handle, figure

In a callback function of a Matlab GUI, I need to catch the ficure handle of a plot created in the command window, and so not within the GUI. If I use simply `gcf` inside the callback, i get the GUI handle and not the handle of the figure. In fact in this callback if I write `close(gcf)`, the GUI closes, and not the figure I want to close.
How can I get the right figure handle?

Comment: What kind of plot did you create through the command window, and how did you create it? Could you please provide the code? (Generally, you solve it using `findobj` or if you create the other figure using `figure(#)` then just use `#`)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your replay!
Lets say in Command window I simply do:
`plot(0,0)`. Now, I launch my gui, and within a callback I want to add some other points/lines inside the previous plot, i tried to get the axes handles doing `h = findobj(gcf,'Type','axes')`, but `gcf` returns the GUI handle, and not the plot handle

Comment: I meant something like: `figure(405); figure(155); figure();` => 
`hFigs = findobj(0,'Type','figure');` then you choose whichever is not `gcf` (`0` is the MATLAB root object).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to @Dev-iL' suggestion, you can use setappdata/getappdata in the root to store and retrieve the figure handle:

```
% Create dummy plot in Command Window
x = 1:100;
plot(x,x.^2);

hfigure = gcf;
setappdata(0,'hfigure',hfigure);
```

and then in your GUI callback:

```
hfigure = getappdata(0,'hfigure');
```

after that you're good to go.